# Sharepoint.SE Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know SharePoint's anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **13 September**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Comment: One really cool thing that one of our sites has done is organize an analog-space meetup. Feel free to get creative!

Comment: Darnit, just realised I'm away next week. :(

Answer (score 6):

Since there's been a giant great ominous silence, I'll make a reasonably feasible suggestion:

**SPSE Blogfest**

Given that the SE infrastructure is already in place ([Arqade for example](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/?blb=1)): The SharePoint community's full of prolific bloggers, and I think SPSE would be a great platform to encourage more high-quality article writing.

There's plenty of starting material already out there on the site (some of @omlin's answers are almost blog articles already!). Sometimes a subject needs more in-depth analysis or broad introductory material than the site's designed for.

Here are some example subjects that may well gain the site more attention:

- Tutorials and reference guides (Client Object Model, Custom Field Types)
- Datasheet Q&A summary ("No")
- Anything to do with 2013 (although I'm loathe to encourage yet more speculation on this subject)
- Pretty much anything from the site's [Greatest Hits list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits)

So how about a blogfest?

Comment: Does this community have a blog site?

Comment: Stack Exchange has the mechanism to provide us with one it seems (see the Arqade link), but we don't have one currently.

Comment: +1 great idea - this is something I've considered on and off for a while. It would be great for some of those "poll" or more discussion oriented questions. We would need to consider how people could contribute. I definitely have some posts from my own blog that would fit.

Comment: @KitMenke I've got a monster Custom Field Type article I need a kick to finish that might fit the "reference guide" category. Possibly the "unreadable tat" category too.